# How to get previous versions of Python Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is there a way to uninstall Selenium Webdriver in linux? I want to reinstall an older version ie 2.33 which worked for me. Can you please let me know the syntax for installing specific version of selenium in linux?

In Selenium website previous release of java are present. Where can I previous versions of Python?

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list?can=1&q=

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do like this:

`pip uninstall selenium`

And:

`pip install selenium==2.33`

Comment: if we dont have pip installed is there any other way to uninstall? Can i try "python setup.py uninstall"?

Comment: You can use pip even if it didn't install the package. So, go ahead install pip and follow the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You can install your required version with following command

```
pip install selenium==2.53.6
```

it will automatically uninstall previous version installed on your system and install your required version.

if you want to update selenium to latest version, then run following command

```
pip install -u selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Installing any previous version of `selenium`

As for installing previous version of selenium you can simply use as the others said.
`pip install selenium== VERSION_YOU_WANT`

###### For Updating to the latest version of `selenium`

`pip install -u selenium` is not working for now.

There is a new version of selenium `4.9` To update to the latest version of `selenium` you can use this command:

`pip install -U selenium`

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: I've changed it with the answer for the question asked. My previous comment was meant for those who were facing the trouble update their selenium version `4.8`. I had a trouble updating. So, thought it would help if anyone come across this page and face trouble updating their selenium.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone want to upgrade or download specific version of selenium then run this in your command prompt- pip install selenium==4.10.0